# How to update / reinstall executable stored in NuGet

Tags: nuget

I would like to use NuGet to avoid adding a 3rd party executable to git repository.

I have a NuGet package with executable published to our NuGet source. Package contents:

```
content\SetupFiles\bigexecutable.exe
```

I've added the NuGet reference to the project in which I want to use the executable. It properly adds the

```
SetupFiles\bigexecutable.exe
```

to the project directory during the NuGet package installation. But if I delete the file from the project directory it is not replaced during the build.

Is it possible that NuGet would verify if the package contents are present before the build and reinstalled the package if something is missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your .exe is being added to the project since you are including it in the `Content` directory. NuGet will not restore items into the project. It will only restore items into the packages directory.

An alternative would be to create a tools NuGet package where the .exe is not added to the project but is available in a `tools` directory relative to the solution's directory.

The [NUnit.ConsoleRunner](https://www.nuget.org/packages/NUnit.ConsoleRunner/) is one example of such a NuGet package where it has all its .exe files in the `tools` directory. Using the tools directory does not cause NuGet to add any files to your project.